# Gsutil not found with Terraform and Cloudbuild

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-build, gsutil

I have a problem with my plan terraform in using cloud build. I cannot use gsutil command in a module terraform, I have an error :

```
Error: Error running command 'gsutil -m rsync -d -r ../../../sources/composer gs://toto/dags/': exit status 127. Output: /bin/sh: gsutil: not found
```

My cloudbuild.yaml :

```
steps:
- id: 'branch name'
  name: 'alpine'
  entrypoint: 'sh'
  args:
    - '-c'
    - |
      echo "***********************"
      echo "$BRANCH_NAME"
      echo "***********************"
...
# [START tf-apply]
- id: 'tf apply'
  name: 'hashicorp/terraform:0.15.0'
  entrypoint: 'sh'
  args:
    - '-c'
    - |
      if [ -d "terraform/environments/$BRANCH_NAME/" ]; then
        cd terraform/environments/$BRANCH_NAME      
        terraform apply -auto-approve
      else
        echo "***************************** SKIPPING APPLYING *******************************"
        echo "Branch '$BRANCH_NAME' does not represent an oficial environment."
        echo "*******************************************************************************"
      fi
# [END tf-apply]
timeout: 3600s
```

My module to put files in gcs :

```
resource "null_resource" "upload_folder_content" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "gsutil -m rsync -d -r ${var.dag_folder_path} ${var.composer_dag_gcs}/"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using the Hashicorp's Terraform image in your step, it is to be expected that `gsutil` it's not included by default and as such you're unable to run that command that your null_resource is defining opposed to what you'd be able to do on your local environment.

In order to overcome that, you could build your own custom image and [push](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling) it to Google Container Registry so you're able to use it afterwards. With that option you will also have more flexibility as you could install whatever dependency your Terraform code has.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's only solution to put files in gcs with cloud build and terraform. Finally we use own jenkins server with terraform and gsutil installed.

Comment: Glad I could help! Jenkins is probably better as you have more control on the environment and with the plugins you can install, there are plenty of handy functionalities to use :)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the actual error line, at the very end, it says this was the output of the command:

```
/bin/sh: gsutil: not found
```

I suspect that `gsutil` is simply not being found on your shell's path.

Perhaps you need to install whatever package `gsutil` is found in?

Comment: I agree with you but the concern is that I am using Cloud Build to run my terraform plan and I cannot install gsutil because it is in serverless mode. I am using the image: hashicorp / terraform: 0.15.0